# Подсчёт количества строк

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица в которой идентификаторы идут не по порядку:

```
CREATE TABLE random(ID INT primary key , Value INT unique )
INSERT INTO random 
values 
(1,1),
(2,3),
(10,7),
(4,10),
(5,16),
(6,17),
(17,33),
(8,21),
(67,27),
(11,41),
(99,25),
(12,13),
(13,23),
(14,29),
(1000,9)
```

Нужно создать дополнительный столбец нумерации строк без использования функции `row_number()`

**Мои попытки:**

Сгенерировал нумерацию вот так:

```
select id, value,  count(*)  over (partition by 1 order by id ) as rnum
from random
```

но данный запрос сортирует по ключу, а нужен исходный порядок.

Можно ли как-то столбец `rnum` "приклеить справа" к исходному запросу `"select * from random"` ?

**Обновлено** 
Таблицу менять нельзя "склейка" нужна в запросе, либо другой запрос в котором
например можно обратиться к строке №7

Comment: А что такое "исходный порядок" SQL вообще не гарантирует порядка записей в таблице, если не указан конкретный order by.

Comment: Столбец должен физически появится в таблице или нужно добиться вывода дополнительного значения SELECT-запросом?

Comment: Если вам нужен "исходный порядок", добавьте в таблицу автоинкременируемый столбец.

Comment: столбец должен участвовать в запросе,физически он не нужен. Исходный порядок имеется ввиду тот, который у  select * from random, менять таблицу нельзя нужен запрос

Comment: может попробуете `rank()`

Answer (score 1):

А почему нельзя ROW_NUMBER()?
Вот вам два варианта с ROW_NUMBER() и c COUNT(*)

```
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER()OVER()rownum,
  COUNT(*)OVER(ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)countnum,
  *
FROM
(values 
(1,1),
(2,3),
(10,7),
(4,10),
(5,16),
(6,17),
(17,33),
(8,21),
(67,27),
(11,41),
(99,25),
(12,13),
(13,23),
(14,29),
(1000,9))T(ID, Value)

rownum  countnum    id  value
1   1   1   1
2   2   2   3
3   3   10  7
4   4   4   10
5   5   5   16
6   6   6   17
7   7   17  33
8   8   8   21
9   9   67  27
10  10  11  41
11  11  99  25
12  12  12  13
13  13  13  23
14  14  14  29
15  15  1000    9
```

Но имейте ввиду, что порядок вывода строк без сортировки в бд не гарантируется.

В частности, оптимизатор может вставить свою сортировку, например для операторов JOIN или UNION, и тогда вы получите не тот результат.

**В общем случае, когда вы используете нумерацию без сортировки - на одним и тех же данных, один и тот же запрос может дать разные результаты!**

(это может зависеть от версии сервера; текущей статистики таблиц - которые влияют на план запроса)